# Is there any way to share image+audio from an android device to a pc without mirroring?

Tags: video, streaming

I have a robot that uses android (API 22) but it doesn't have screen mirroring. One of our clients wants to stream the screen and internal audio (not the voices from people outside) of this robot to their pc, but I have no idea how or even if it's possible to do without mirroring. I tried AnyDesk but it doesn't allow me to share audio.

I've been looking for possible solutions but I havent found anything.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thank you, best regards.

Comment: If the destination can also be a TV instead of a PC you could try to share the screen via Chromecast. You just need the cheap Chromecast dongle as receiver (the full-HD version without AndroidTV-UI is sufficient).

Comment: Unfortunately, the client insists they need it on a PC, but thanks for the suggestion!